# install heapster or metric server in kubernetes for horizontal pod autoscaling

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, autoscaling, kubernetes-pod, heapster

how to install heapster or metric server to get pod metrics in kubernetes.
I need those pod metrics for using it to horizontal pod auto-scaling. I'm using Digital Ocean cloud cluster.
deployment file is in the screenshot below [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to first download the following files:

```
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/heapster/master/deploy/kube-config/influxdb/grafana.yaml > grafana.yaml
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/heapster/master/deploy/kube-config/influxdb/heapster.yaml > heapster.yaml
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/heapster/master/deploy/kube-config/influxdb/influxdb.yaml > influxdb.yaml
curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/heapster/master/deploy/kube-config/rbac/heapster-rbac.yaml > heapster-rbac.yaml
```

Then create the following service instance of grafana, influxdb and heapster:

```
$ kubectl create -f grafana.yaml
deployment "monitoring-grafana" created
service "monitoring-grafana" created

$ kubectl create -f heapster.yaml
serviceaccount "heapster" created
deployment "heapster" created
service "heapster" created

$ kubectl create -f influxdb.yaml
deployment "monitoring-influxdb" created
service "monitoring-influxdb" created

$ kubectl create -f heapster-rbac.yaml
clusterrolebinding "heapster" created
```

Follow this tutorial for test your autoscaling pods:

https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/autoscale-application-on-kubernetes-cluster/

Hope this helps.

EDIT: Resource request in your deployment file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  containers:
  - name: db
    image: mysql
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: "password"
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
  - name: wp
    image: wordpress
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
```

resources and request should be there in your deployment files so that HPA can access it to autoscale.

Comment: "kubectl get hpa"  the TARGETS remains unknown/25 %. I think the hpa cant retrieve pod metrics. what should I do now? @prafull

Comment: You need to specify resource requests in the Pod spec section of your deployment for the HPA to be able to display that information

Comment: I followed the link you posted above. Where should I specify resource request? 
(I'm new to kubernetes)@prafull

Comment: I have edited my ans, that have resources request in spec section, you must have those to access metrics of mem and cpu by HPA

Comment: resources and requests were there already, (screenshot of the deployment file is added to the question ) @prafull

Comment: can you add `kubectl get hpa` results?

Comment: Heapster is being deprecated right?
Anyway, I tried with your proposed answer, And I see from dashboard pods logs that :
```No metric client provided. Skipping metrics.```

I looked it up and it seems this is intentional in favor to a feature thats being worked up on.
https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/3147

Answer (score 0):

Heapster is Deprecated in Latest Kubernetes. Fetching metrics from Heapster is deprecated as of Kubernetes 1.11.

Installing with metrics-server worked for me :

```
kubectl apply -f https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases/latest/download/components.yaml
```

Source :

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/resource-metrics-pipeline/#metrics-server
- https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server